# Regular expressions and Xpath on Maps

Tags: php, regex, xpath, dictionary

I'm trying to scrape some information from a map using xpath i need the following information latitude and longitude. here is my code so far

```
foreach($xpath->query('//script[@type="text/javascript"]') as $table5)
 {
$src= $xpath->query('.//text()', $table5)->item(0)->nodeValue;
preg_match('/latitude\/=\([\d.-]+)/', $src, $m);
list(, $lat, $lng) = $m;
}
```

the site i'm scrapping has this section that i need the lat and long

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var latitude = -1.283; ///a need regular expression to get this value -1.283
var longitude = 36.817;
var zoom = 12;
$(document).ready(function(){
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom);
map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not quite correct (you need to take whitespace into account, and you've accidentally escaped the left parenthesis). Try this (using an [online regex tester](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html)):

```
/latitude = ([\d.-]+)/
```

Comment: foreach($xpath->query('//script[@type="text/javascript"]') as $table5)
 {
$src= $xpath->query('.//text()', $table5)->item(0)->nodeValue;
preg_match('\'var latitude = ([\\d.-]+); var longitude = ([\\d.-]+);\'', $src, $m);
print_r($m);
} so i edited but it returns an empty array output Array()

Comment: Did you try the online regular expression tester, using your first suggestion, then my answer and lastly your new attempt? (Hint: do not forget whitespace)

Comment: does it return tha latitude value?

Answer (score 0):

**Pure XPath**:

**For latitude**:

```
substring-before(substring-after(., 'var latitude = '), ';')
```

when this XPath expression is evaluated (assuming the provided `script` element is the context node), the result of this evaluation is:

```
-1.283
```

**For longitude**:

```
substring-before(substring-after(., 'var longitude = '), ';')
```

when this XPath expression is evaluated (assuming the provided `script` element is the context node), the result of this evaluation is:

```
36.817
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "substring-before(
        substring-after(/*/head/script[1], 'var latitude = '),
        ';'
                    )"/>

=======
<xsl:text/>

  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "substring-before(
        substring-after(/*/head/script[1], 'var longitude = '),
        ';'
                    )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document:**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var latitude = -1.283; ///a need regular expression to get this value -1.283
    var longitude = 36.817;
    var zoom = 12;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>Hello</body>
</html>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the result is copied to the output**:

```
-1.283

=======
36.817
```

Comment: i don't know how xslt works i'm kinda new to all this what do i need to do to integrate it with my php script?

Comment: @user1376479: You don't need to use XSLT at all -- I used it only to show the actual results of evaluating the two XPath expressions. Just evaluate these two XPath expressions in your PHP program.

Comment: so i put the $xpath->query(substring-before(substring-after(., 'var longitude = '), ';') or how does it work?

Comment: @user1376479: I am not a specialist in PHP -- you are supposed to know how to evaluate an XPath expression in your programming language.